# protobuf-net serialization performance of large primitive arrays

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have 2 questions regarding the serialization of very large objects.

**1:** What happens when you serialize an object >> 2GB with length prefix? On first sight it looks like  the length prefix is an integer. Does prototobuf-net support serializing such large objects with legth prefix?

**2:** Serialization of the following class seems to take forever (for 950,000,000 integers):

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Xyz
{
    [ProtoMember(1, IsPacked = true)]
    public int[] Field { get; set; }
}
```

Quick serialization code is:

```
int nn = 950000000;
Xyz xyz = new Xyz();
xyz.Field = new int[nn];
for (int i = 0; i < nn; i++)
{
    xyz.Field[i] = i + 1;
}

RuntimeTypeModel xyzModel = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();
xyzModel.Add(typeof(Xyz), true);
TypeModel realModel = xyzModel.Compile();

using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\file.bin", FileMode.Create))
{
    realModel.Serialize(fs, xyz);
}
```

For brevity I checked if it is a problem with the disk etc.. by using:

```
using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nn; i++)
    {
        bw.Write(xyz.Field[i]);
    }
}
```

Writing everything with `BinaryWriter` directly takes very little time even for this number of elements.

I would expect something slower when using `protobuf-net` but I was hoping still practical. I waited 15 minutes for the serialization and it has still not finished.

Is my usage wrong or is it expected that it is this slow?

---

**NOTE** This is just an example which is part of a bigger solution. I am interested in serializing such things with protobuf-net, even if for this particular example the obvious choice is to write all the integers manually :).

Regards, Iulian

Comment: Most things in .NET have a `Length` or a `Count` of type `int`.  What have you got with a length larger than int.MaxValue?  I'm not sure data of that size is really the bailiwick of protocol buffers.  What benefit do you hope to get from protocol buffers and blobs of data that large?

Comment: @Peter I need to send complex entities over the network in a binary format that can be read by C++/Java clients. Basically I need good interop support for binary serialization. Protocol buffers are good at binary interop. Some of these entities are larger than `int.MaxValue`. They can be for example 3 GB or 5 GB . I can think of various ways of achieving this if direct serialization with `protobuf-net` is not possible, but they are more elaborate than just marking the field with an attribute :).

Comment: I think you're seeing that that interop is expensive (e.g big-endian, little-endian support, etc.) and that for large amounts of data it becomes an issue.  `BinaryWriter` offloads the endian stuff such that the other end is forced to deal with it if it needs to.  You may not even need that either.  This is likely an edge case, maybe Marc Gravell will chime in with some thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. at the wire level, "varint" should be fine - it can hold up to 64 bits; however, I doubt that the *implementation* has been tested beyond 2GB sizes; note that google's recommended usage of protocol buffers is much smaller than that
2. yes, serializing a billion things could take quite some considerable time; I haven't looked at that specific array scenario, but if I had to guess: it is trying to buffer it in-memory first; that could be a scenario I look at to optimize